# Do modern variable frequency drives perform power factor correction?

Tags: power-factor-correction, vfd, ac-motor

Do modern variable frequency drives (VFDs) perform power factor correction?

I can't find info to see whether VFDs do power factor correction. If they do, how good are they?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a universal answer.

Comment: The product sales literature is bound to make a big deal of it if they do

Comment: They ought to ... now, whether they do ...

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the type of controller.

**As a rule of thump:** The more "well known" the brand is, the more likely it is.

**The reason is:** Usually, private households are not charged for reactive power draw. Industrial consumers are. Therefore, in regard to ever increasing energy prices, PFC becomes very interesting at scale. And industrial factorys are - at least too me - not known for buying cheap equipment. They buy what fits the requirements, and these are typically "well known" brands.

Answer (score -1):

On the overall affect on a facility power factor:  Adding VFD drives to a facility typically improves the overall power factor for the facility due to the capacitors on the DC bus.

In the case where a traditional across the line inductive motor is operated, resulting is a lagging power factor.  If you add a VFD to the the existing motor  - you have gone from negatively affecting the facility power factor to positively affecting the power factor.

Comment: The rectifier in front of the DC bus creates some very *interesting* reactive power waveforms (i.e. current only in spikes just before the AC voltage peaks). Technically capacitive but definitely not ideal power factor correction...

Comment: @MattS That's when the VFD doesn't have a PFC front-end. With PFC, the load approximates a resistive heater. Where things get interesting is PFC regenerative front-ends that can push energy both ways: from mains to DC link, and from DC link to mains. That's used when large inertias are being spun up and stopped repeatedly, and avoids wasting the braking energy. Also very handy when load testing high power supply systems: the load's absorbed energy can be regenerated onto the mains.

Comment: Indeed, but PFC inside a VFD doesn't usually help the rest of the facility too...

Comment: Heh, I suppose there is some truth to that, but still not as stated: the mains input filter will have some ~uF of line-to-line capacitance, which will contribute a small amount of phase shift (displacement power factor) correction. The pulsating (harmonic) content however dominates at any meaningful power output.